# 2 passwords for login

Tags: linux, users, password

On Linux, I would like to to set up a user account in such a way that the user would have to enter 2 passwords to log in. Is this possible, and what would be the implications of this?

Comment: What is the advantage of having to enter two passwords to login (unless you really hate your users)

Comment: you may wish to alter password complexity i.e. 36 char long, with 3 uppercase, 4 special char and all. to be change every fortnight, no reusing last 100 password.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to configure pam to use with two different passwords?](http://superuser.com/questions/896158/how-to-configure-pam-to-use-with-two-different-passwords)

Answer (score 3):

Reading between the lines, what you want to configure is two-factor authentication. This will require an additional "piece of information" in addition to the password for the user to log in.

There are a multitude of ways of implementing it, but a few popular options are:

- The open source [Google Authenticator](https://github.com/google/google-authenticator).
- Using a third party product like [YubiKey](https://www.yubico.com/) - see [this guide](https://www.yubico.com/applications/computer-login/linux/) for more information.

In both cases, PAM modules are available so all system logins (console, `ssh`, etc) can be configured to use two-factor authentication.

Answer (score 1):

A quick search turned up [Two Factor SSH Setup](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-protect-ssh-with-two-factor-authentication) which is a simple walkthrough of the steps required for setup.